# process file line by line does not work in ksh

Tags: loops, unix, while-loop, ksh, do-while

This looks simple but i am not sure why it wont read beyond first line if I try to do any processing on data i read from file.

code:

```
while IFS="" read -r line
do
 u=`echo $line | awk '{print $4}'`
 h=`echo $line | awk '{print $2}'|cut -f1 -d'.'`
 echo "$h : $u"
 ssh $h grep $u /etc/shadow
done < "/var/tmp/user_data"
```

user_data is a file with one line for each user/system like:

```
xxx unixhost01  xxx admin69 xxx... ....
xxx host xxx uid xxx... ...
    ...
    ...
```

when i run this code it only works on first line then exit. debug in shell shows no issues. when i run it without the ssh operation/command it processes whole data file.

shell is ksh:

```
# ps
   PID TTY         TIME CMD
  1424 pts/138     0:00 ps
 18521 pts/138     0:02 ksh
```

on executing it only prints (the first line):

```
unixhost01 : admin69
admin69:$1$gFfcEQETGZAo6W0:17599:0:90:10:::
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in `ssh` itself since it consumes standard input so the next time you loop around to get another line, there aren't any left. You can verify this by changing your command to:

```
ssh $h cat
```

and seeing that it outputs the rest of your file during the first `ssh` session.

You can fix this in at least two ways, the first by simply *disconnecting* your `ssh` from standard input:

```
ssh $h grep $u /etc/shadow </dev/null
```

The second (needed if you actually *want* to interact with the target box) is to use a *different* file handle for the input file stream:

```
while IFS="" read -u3 -r line ; do   # reads file #3
    blah blah blah
done 3</var/tmp/user_data            # sends data via file #3
```